# Си методы нахождения корня функции

Tags: c, численные-методы

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
double fc1(double x){
return (3*powf(log(x), 2) + 6 * log(x) - 5);
}
double fc2(double x){
return (0.6 * powf(3, x) - 2.3 * x - 3);
}
double fc1pr(double x){
return (6*log(x) / x + 6./x);
}
double fc2pr(double x){
return (0.659167 * pow(3, x) - 2.3);
}
double fc3(double x){
return ( (-0.1667) * (3*powf(log(x), 2) + 6 * log(x) - 5) + x);
}
double fc4(double x){
return ((-0.06453) * (0.6 * powf(3, x) - 2.3 * x - 3) + x);
}
double dihot (double a,double b,double f(double x), double epsil){
    double x=0;
    //if (fabs(f((a + b)/2.0)) < 1){
        while (fabs(a-b)>epsil){
            x = (a+b)/2.0;
            if (f(a)*f(x) > 0.0){
            a = x;
            }
            else{
            b = x;
            }
        }
    //}
    return x;
}
double newthon(double a, double b, double f1(double x), double f2(double x), double epsil){
double x = (a +b) / 2.0;
while(fabs(f1(x)/f2(x))>=epsil){
x -= f1(x)/f2(x);
}
return x;
}
double iter (double a, double b, double f(double), double epsil){
double x = (a+b)/2.0;
while (fabs(x - f(x))>=epsil){
x = f(x);
}
return x;
}
int main(void) {
    double epsil = 1.0;
    while (1 + epsil/2 > 1){
        epsil /=2;
    }
    printf("Машинное эпсилон = %.16e\n", epsil);
    printf("Функция(номер 7) 3*(ln(x))^2 + 6*ln(x) - 5\n");
    printf("Метод Дихотомии \t%f\n", dihot(1.0,3.0,fc1,epsil));
    printf("Метод Итераций \t%f\n", iter(1.0,3.0,fc3,epsil));
    printf("Метод Ньютона \t%.7f\n", newthon(1.0,3.0,fc1,fc1pr,epsil));
    printf("~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~\n");
    printf("Функция(номер 8) 0.6*3^x - 2.3*x - 3\n");
    printf("Метод Дихотомии \t%.10f\n", dihot(2.0,3.0,fc2,epsil));
    printf("Метод Итераций \t%.10f\n", iter(2.0,3.0,fc4,epsil));
    printf("Метод Ньютона \t%.10f", newthon(2.0,3.0,fc2,fc2pr,epsil));
    return 0;
    }
```

Задача состоит в нахождении корня уравнения по 3 методам, fc3 fc4 - функции для метода итераций для функций fc1 fc2 соответственно, f1pr f2pr - производные функций f1 f2. Есть заккомментированный вывод, он не работает, при этом не понимаю почему, вот функции[image: Функции соответствуют f1 f2]

Comment: Спасибо за информацию, но в чем **вопрос**?

Comment: Подправил вопрос, согласен, что было непонятно, в чем проблема

Comment: _Есть заккомментированный вывод, он не работает_ - почему ты думаешь что он не работает?

Comment: А что за хитрое условие `if (fabs(f((a + b)/2.0)) < 1){`? Что оно должно делать и зачем?

Comment: Необязательная Проверка на сходимость

Comment: Почему вы считаете это проверкой сходимости? Здесь куда логичней проверка корректности диапазона `if (f(a)*f(b) < 0) ...`

Answer (score 1):

Просто работать возле машинной точности — дело очень, гм... нездоровое.

Добавим отладочный вывод и посмотрим

```
    while (fabs(a-b)>epsil){
        printf("a = %lf, b = %lf, eps = %lg\n",a,b,b-a);
        x = (a+b)/2.0;
```

его результаты зацикливаются на

```
a = 2.419982, b = 2.419982, eps = 4.44089e-16
```

Просто слишком задранная точность.

Для итераций отладочный вывод дает

```
x = 2.419982, f(x) = 2.419982  eps = 3.20428e-08
x = 2.419982, f(x) = 2.419982  eps = -7.39745e-08
x = 2.419982, f(x) = 2.419982  eps = 2.58194e-08
x = 2.419982, f(x) = 2.419982  eps = 2.96515e-08
x = 2.419982, f(x) = 2.419982  eps = 3.40523e-08
x = 2.419982, f(x) = 2.419982  eps = -7.16668e-08
x = 2.419982, f(x) = 2.419982  eps = 2.84696e-08
x = 2.419982, f(x) = 2.419982  eps = 3.2695e-08
.....
```

Ньютона оставляю вам в качестве самостоятельной работы :)

P.S. Отладочный вывод — отличное средство для понимания того, что происходит. Если бы профессором был я :), я бы этому учил, наверное, самому первому. Этот метод успешно работал, когда еще никаких отладчиков не было...

P.P.S. Рекомендовал бы для методов итерации и Ньютона просто на бумажке и с калькулятором прикинуть точности вычислений.